# How to initialize named tuple in python enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, enums

I have a Enum which is used as a column datatype in SqlALchemy. But I need more properties of the Enum to make it accessible for the code's other functionality.

This is what I have created till now:

```
class ServerHealth(Enum):
"""Status of Server health."""

    HealthStatus = namedtuple("HealthStatus", ["name", "low_bound", "high_bound"])
    High = HealthStatus(name="High", low_bound=5, high_bound=24)
    Fair = HealthStatus(name="Fair", low_bound=3, high_bound=5)
    Low = HealthStatus(name="Low", low_bound=0, high_bound=3)

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def value(self):
        return self.name
```

This is used somewhere in sqlalchemy model as well, so I need to keep it the way it doesn't break-

```
class Server(Base):
    server_health = Column(ENUM(ServerHealth), nullable=True)
```

I need the "name" of namedtuple as the columns value in DB. As per my understanding the value attribute is used by sqlalchemy, so I have overwritten them and the value works as expected i.e.

```
>>>ServerHealth.High.value
"High"
```

but when I try to access low_bound and high_bound it breaks

```
>>>ServerHealth.High.low_bound
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [77], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ServerHealth.High.low_bound

AttributeError: 'ServerHealth' object has no attribute 'low_bound'
```

Now what function should I overwrite in order to get that working without breaking db initialization.

Comment: "As per my understanding the value attribute is used by sqlalchemy" - when I check the docs, I see a statement that the values are absolutely **not** used. SQLAlchemy uses the names.

Comment: Anyway, your enum instances *don't* have a `low_bound` attribute. That's an attribute of (what *would* be) the value (except you overrode `value`).

Comment: right.. so if I remove the overwrite.. I can access like `ServerHealth.High.value.low_bound`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
class ServerHealth(Enum):
    """
    Status of Server health.
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, low_bound, high_bound):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = name
        member.low_bound = low_bound
        member.high_bound = high_bound
        return member
    #
    HIGH = "High", 5, 24
    FAIR = "Fair", 3, 5
    LOW = "Low", 0, 3
```

and in use:

```
>>> ServerHealth.High.low_bound
5
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.